# Codewars Madhav array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

A Madhav array has the following property:

a[0] = a[1] + a[2] = a[3] + a[4] + a[5] = a[6] + a[7] + a[8] + a[9] = ...

Complete the function/method that returns true if the given array is a Madhav array, otherwise it returns false.

Edge cases: An array of length 0 or 1 should not be considered a Madhav array as there is nothing to compare.

Test.assertDeepEquals( isMadhavArray([2,1,1]),true);

Test.assertDeepEquals( isMadhavArray([2,1,1,4,-1,-1]),true);

```
function isMadhavArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 3) {
    return false;
  }
  
  let goal = arr[0];
  arr.shift();
  
  let n = 2;
  
  while (arr.length > 0) { 
    let remove_items = arr.splice(0, n);
    
    let sum = remove_items.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
    
    if (goal == sum) {
      n++
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true; 
}
```

According to my solution, it passes 111 out of 113 tests, what am I missing?

Comment: Which tests fail? Add details to the question

Comment: tests not visible

Comment: Should `if (arr.length < 3)` be `if (arr.length < 2)` or even `if (arr.length <= 1)`otherwise you automatically discard `a[0] = a[1]`

Comment: i only see one problem, and that is that arr.length should be less than 2 at the start.
so change that to if(arr.length < 2) or better to if(arr.length <= 1)

Comment: Why so much splicing and reducing, when this could be done using a simply `for` loop ...

Comment: If I do 2, it fails 4 tests in total, I don't understand why.

Comment: I tried to solve it with the first method that came to my mind.

Comment: The array must have at least 3 entries to satisfy the conditions so the test is correct

Comment: why is `[2,1,1,4,-1,-1]` `true`?

Comment: @NinaScholz `2 = 1 + 1 = 4 + (-1) + (-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't check that you are really adding *n* items. It could be that at the end of the array there are fewer elements left than needed to make a sum of *n* terms. In that case, `splice` will just return the shorter array, and you'll make the sum of those. If then the sum still matches the target value, you have a false positive.

Here is an example input where your code returns the wrong result:

```
isMadhavArray([2,1,1,1,1]); // Should be false
```

So fix your code with this extended `if` condition:

```
    if (goal == sum && remove_items.length == n) {
```

Alternatively, you could do a one-time check at the start of the function to ensure that the array's length is such that the last slice will have the required length, or in other words, that the array's length is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

```
if (array.length < 3 || Math.sqrt(8*array.length+1) % 1) return false;
```

NB: As stated in comments, splicing your array is not efficient. It is better to not mutate the array, and just iterate over it.

Comment: Incredibly hard for ChatGPT to solve this one